# How to focus at the end of the text in the Google search input field?

Tags: javascript, focus

How to focus at the end of the text in an input field using Javascript.

I want to move the mouse over the input field to focus on it, and the curse is at the end of the text.

I just use the Event as the following, the curse is at the first.

```
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        if (e.target.localName ==='input'){
            e.target.focus();
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            e.target.blur();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safer solution where you don't modify the contents/value of the input field is by triggering the selection of the value.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  let elm = e.target;
  if (elm.localName ==='input'){
    elm.focus();
    elm.selectionStart = elm.value.length;
    elm.selectionEnd = elm.value.length;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
  e.target.blur();
});
```

```html
<input value="hello"/>
```

Comment: Thx, it is better than the first one, which changes the value and it influent the function that popup an icons bar when focusing the input field.

Comment: @lyscop .. glad to know. Please mark the answer that works for you as a solution so this question will be closed.

Comment: Oops, it shows an error, `e.target.selectionStart = e.target.value.length;` Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: it's not `e` . it should be `elm` .. check the code properly.

Comment: @lyscop .. can you post the code you're using?

Comment: I put it on Greasyfork https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/418551-%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7-%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%A8%E8%81%9A%E7%84%A6/code

Comment: @lyscop Working fine for me

Comment: I find it if the input is null, the SelectionStart can get the value, whether I should add a judge? https://i.imgur.com/uSnMeAD.png

Comment: Are you sure Google's box works as an input field? I don't think so.

Comment: Aha, so it is the input field should not be null, I add a judge `if(e.target.value){`

Answer (score 1):

When focusing the input, you can erase the input value and set the same value again.

```js
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  if (e.target.localName ==='input'){
    e.target.focus();
    var val = e.target.value; //store the value of the element
    e.target.value = '';      //clear the value of the element
    e.target.value = val;     //set that value back. 
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
  e.target.blur();
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" size="30" name="search"/>
```

Comment: does it work for you, @lyscop? if then, can you please upvote?

Comment: Really not sure if changing the value here is a good idea as there can be other functions that might impact on value change of this input field.

Comment: It recovers the value immediately, so there won't any problem.

Comment: Irrespective of that, changing a value to and fro to achieve something is not a good practice. There'll be some unknown function that's attached to it and it might inadvertently get triggered on this property change, especially applicable if you are using some libraries/plugins :)